# error in if return in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement, return

```
def vertify(a:Int):Int= {
    val result = 3
    if(a>4) {
        val result = a
    }
    return result
}
```

I defined the function above,then used it:

```
scala> vertify(5)
res4: Int = 3
```

Why is the result 3 and not 5?

Comment: could you please provide more details to the question and other approaches you have tried to resolve problem.

Comment: you should read about the basics of Scala values and variables, and scopes

Answer (score 6):

```
if(a>4) {
  val result = a
}
```

this is creating a second `val` named `result` that is only scoped (visible) inside the `if` block, so the return statement always returns the value defined on line 2.

A `val` can not be reassigned so you would need to use a `var` if you needed to change the value:

```
var result = 3
if (a > 4) {
  // no `var` or `val` prefix indicates we are
  // referring to an existing variable that's already declared
  result = a
}
```

but for a simple case like this you can avoid the variable and use:

```
def vertify(a: Int): Int = if (a > 4) a else 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You're defining a new value inside the if block. Do it like this:

```
def vertify(a:Int):Int= {
  val result = 3
  if(a>4) {
    a
  } else {
    result
  }
}
```

Or shorter:

```
def vertify(a: Int): Int = if (a > 4) a else 3
```